# Spring syntax for setting a Class object?

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to set a property in spring to, not an instance of a class, but the class object itself? i.e.

Rather than

```
<bean>
   <property name="prototype" class="a.b.c.Foo">...
```

giving you an instance of "Foo", something like:

```
<bean>
  <property name="prototype" class="java.lang.Class" value="a.b.c.Foo.class"...
```

edit:
best (working) solution so far - use the normal instantiation and derive the class in the setter. In terms of solutions I think this we'd describe this as "cheating":

```
<bean class="Bar">
   <property name="prototype" class="a.b.c.Foo">...


public class Bar{
        public void setPrototype(Object o){
                this.prototypeClass=o.getClass();
```

edit:
dtsazza's method works as well.

edit:
pedromarce's method works as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
<bean>
   <property name="x">
      <value type="java.lang.Class">a.b.c.Foo</value>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

That should work.

Answer (score 11):

You could certainly use the [static factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s03.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) Class.forName(), if there's no more elegant syntax (and I don't believe there is):

```
<property name="x">
   <bean class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
      <constructor-arg value="a.b.c.Foo"/>
   </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: I upvoted this, because it seemed like a good suggestion. Strangely enough, though, spring is complaining with a "ClassNotFoundException" for java.lang.Class.

Comment: Never mind, that exception was due to a misconfiguration:) Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No. With a bean tag you instruct Spring on how to instantiate a class.

Answer (score 0):

Would <property name="x" class="a.b.c.Foo.class"> work? That should be an instance of a Class object...

Comment: no, that'll give you a ClassNotFound, as there's no such thing as a Foo.class class defined.