# Spring : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/lang.Class

Tags: spring, class, configuration, classnotfoundexception, java.lang.class

I'm creating beans with the following property

```
  <property name="classe">
     <value type="java.lang.Class">foo.bar.SomeClass</value>
  </property>
```

The property "classe" is of type Class.

just like someone hinted on the following question : [Spring syntax for setting a Class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601015/spring-syntax-for-setting-a-class-object)

The problem is that I'm having this exception when deploying my application :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/lang.Class
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:280)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.TypedStringValue.resolveTargetType(TypedStringValue.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveTargetType(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:163)
```

It looks like Steve B. in the question I linked had the same problem and it was related to some spring configuration. I'm ***very*** new to spring and dont really know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What about simply `<property name="classe" value="foo.bar.SomeClass"/>`? Spring should figure out the correct type based on `classe` property type, which is `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: @Tomasz It actually tries to convert it to java.lang.String : `org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'classe'`

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? I just successfully tested it with Spring 3.1, but I'm pretty sure it works with Spring 3.0/2.5.x as well.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I'm using Spring 2.0, your solution worked, I just realized I made a mistake while typing. Can you post your solution as an answer so I can mark this post as Answered and upvote you ?

Comment: Please post the code of the setter.

Comment: @Ralph The question has been answered by Tomasz, it's finally working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply:

```
<property name="classe" value="foo.bar.SomeClass"/>
```

Spring should figure out the correct type based on `classe` property type, which is `java.lang.Class`. I just successfully tested it with Spring 3.1, but I'm pretty sure it works with Spring 3.0/2.5.x as well.