# Cant properly wire java.lang.Class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am trying to make project and have problem with wiring java class lang.
My spring config.

```
<bean id="userService" class="com.event.services.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userRepository" ref="userRepository"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="userRepository" class="com.event.repositories.UserRepository">
    <property name="entityClass">
        <bean class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
            <constructor-arg value="com.event.domain.User"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Classes:
    package com.event.repositories;

```
import com.event.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends JPARepository<String, User> implements UserBonusRepository {

@Override
public User findByKey(String id) {
    return em.find(entityClass, id);
}

@Override
public Iterable<User> findByKeys(Iterable<String> ids) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void persist(User entity) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public User merge(User entity) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void remove(User entity) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void saveAll(Iterable<User> entities) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public boolean isUserValid(String userName, String password) {
    User user = em.find(entityClass, userName);

    if (user == null || !user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

In JpaRepository i have this

```
@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;
@Autowired
public Class<T> entityClass;
```

Problem:
    No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
I was trying to fix this and find this 
[Spring syntax for setting a Class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601015/spring-syntax-for-setting-a-class-object) but this isnt helping. Does someone know how to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Can you show the stack trace please

Comment: Replace autowired property with constructor injection instead. With your current configuration this class is not reusable, and you would need to add an qualifier to your class property. Secondly you are mixing xml bean definition with annotation.

Comment: What's the point of autowiring or configuring the class of the repository? Why not just add a no-arg constructor calling super(User.class)? And why do you use XML to define your beans instead of just using classpath scanning and annotations?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for quick answers. I excluded xml config and annotated service class and repository class with service and repository annotation. But now when i run program my repository class in userService is null. Thats why i tried to configure it through xml. I thought that if I annotate my repository class with repository annotation it woudlnt be null but thats not the case. Do you know maybe how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance. @JBNizet

Comment: You need to provide more information. How do you configure spring? Is com.event.repositories part of the scanned packages?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet. I think i misinformed you in last comment. I still have <bean name="userRepository" class="com.event.repositories.UserRepository">
    </bean> in my xml because when I delete that bean i got exception: No qualifying bean of type 'com.event.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
 In my xml I have
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.event"/> Repo is in package com.event.repositories.Do you need some more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this :

Remove

```
@Autowired
```

From `public Class<T> entityClass;`

And update your xml like this

```
<bean name="userRepository" class="com.event.repositories.UserRepository">
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**

Another solutions are:

1. Make `JpaRepository` abstract by making method getEntityClass abstract and use it where you need class type and remove entityClass field. Child class will provide EntityClass by implementing this method.
2. Make `JpaRepository` (abstract, or not depending on your design ) and remove entityClass field and add a method to discover parameterized types at runtime and use it where you need class type , for example :

> ```
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
>     private Class<T> getEntityClass() {   
>          return (Class<T>) ( (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];  
>     }
> ```
>
> **Argument index 1 because T is the second parameterized type defined**

3. Use superclass constructor to pass entityClass type in `UserRepository`  `super(User.class);`

**Note that i have removed entityClass wiring from xml**

Comment: I have tried that now and i think that solved my problem but I have another one now. 
 Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'entityClass' of bean class [com.event.repositories.UserRepository]: Bean property 'entityClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
I included setters and getters for entityClass and entityClass is public field.

Comment: Can you post methods and generic parameterized types definition of JpaRepository

Comment: Sure.
public Class<T> entityClass;

    public Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        return entityClass;
    }

    public void setEntityClass(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
And this is JPA contructor called from subclass with User.class
public JPARepository(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

Comment: I meant  class parameterized types definition, public class JpaRepository<...,...> ...{ . And subclass UserRepository not uses this constructor ?? Why ? There is default constructor ?

Comment: Thank you very much Hassen, that solved my problem, 1. one solution is what I was looking for but that didnt come to my mind. I have problem with repository wiring now but i will try to google it and solve it by myself. Cheers. :)

Comment: @Spasoje no problem. Do not forget to check 